# How to filter using a checkbox in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I have one checkbox filter that does work. but when I try to make another set of filters it doesn't allow it.
the second filter just doesn't do anything.
I'm using a predicate in both filters as there isn't a ready to use filter for checkbox.

This is my Component :

```
export class ContainersPageComponent implements OnInit {

  tableColumn = ['AITOR','SOG_MCOLH','GOBH_MCOLH','AORKH_MCOLH','MCOLH_N7','MCOLH_AAAA', 'TAOR_QTSR_EBRI','QOD_MCHSN','STTOS_RASHI_4_1',
'LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI','LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR','LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH'];

  p :number = 1;
  dataSource : any = new MatTableDataSource;
  public show:boolean = false;
  public tableHide:any = 'Show';
  searchText: string = "";
  autoFilter : any;
  clientType : string;
  storageType: any;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;


  filterCheckboxes: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  filterParamasBoxes : BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

  constructor(private marinService:MarinServiceService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result) => {
     //Data
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
      //Paginator
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      //AutoFilter Form 1st page
      this.clientType = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('clientType');
      this.storageType= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('storageTypes');
      console.log('The Client name is : '+this.clientType+'  '+'The storage Facility is : '+this.storageType);
      //CheckBox Filter
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Container, filter: any) => {
        return filter.split(',').every((item: any) => data.SOG_MCOLH.indexOf(item) !== -1);
      };
      this.filterCheckboxes.subscribe((newFilterValue: any[]) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = newFilterValue.join(',');
      });
    });
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data : Container,filterParam : any) => {
      return filterParam.split(',').every((paramItem: any) => data.LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR.indexOf(paramItem) !== -1);
    };
    this.filterParamasBoxes.subscribe((paramFilterValue: any[]) => {
      this.dataSource.filterParam = paramFilterValue.join(',');
    })
  }



  toggle(){
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show) {
      this.tableHide = "Hide";
    } else {
      this.tableHide = "Show";
    }
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  public getRowsValue(flag) {
    if (flag === null) {
      return this.dataSource.length;
    } else {
      return this.dataSource.filter(i => (i.state == flag)).length;
    }
  }

  addFilter(change: MatCheckboxChange) {
    if (this.filterCheckboxes.value.some((a: any) => a === change.source.value)) {
      this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.filter((a: any) => a !== change.source.value));
    } else {
      this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.concat(change.source.value));
    }
  }
  paramFilter(changeParam: MatCheckboxChange){
    if (this.filterParamasBoxes.value.some((a: any) => a === changeParam.source.value)) {
      this.filterParamasBoxes.next(this.filterParamasBoxes.value.filter((a: any) => a !== changeParam.source.value));
    } else {
      this.filterParamasBoxes.next(this.filterParamasBoxes.value.concat(changeParam.source.value));
    }
}
```

This is my `HTML` :

```
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="MRR" (change)="paramFilter($event)">MRR</mat-checkbox>

  <div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  [hidden]="!show" matSort >
      <!-- Location  -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="AITOR">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AITOR}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
          <!-- Type  -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="SOG_MCOLH">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Container Type </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.SOG_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
              <!-- Height  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="GOBH_MCOLH">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Height </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.GOBH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>    
              <!-- Length  -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="AORKH_MCOLH">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Lenght </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AORKH_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
              </ng-container> 
               <!-- Number  -->
               <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_N7">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Container Number </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_N7}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container> 
                    <!-- Name AAAA  -->
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="MCOLH_AAAA">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Container Name </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.MCOLH_AAAA}} </mat-cell>
                      </ng-container>  
                     <!-- QTSR Hebrow  -->
                     <ng-container matColumnDef="TAOR_QTSR_EBRI">
                     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Site </mat-header-cell>
                     <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.TAOR_QTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                     </ng-container>   
                                  <!-- Storage Code  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="QOD_MCHSN">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Storage Code </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.QOD_MCHSN}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                 <!-- Status  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="STTOS_RASHI_4_1">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.STTOS_RASHI_4_1}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>      
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer MQOTSR </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_MQOTSR_EBRI}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESN </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
                                  <!-- MQOTSR Hebrow  -->
                                  <ng-container matColumnDef="LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH">
                                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Code Customer </mat-header-cell>
                                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.LQOCH_QOD_LQOCH}} </mat-cell>
                                    </ng-container>
```

Added stackblitz `link` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/marin-project-stackblitz
Do note that yo wont see any data as its an internal `API` service.

I have tried changing values and nothing seems to work.
I have tried moving the filter inside the `NgOnInit`

Comment: Could you please add stackblitz  example  ?

Comment: do you have only checkboxes or will there be a possibility of having a search filter as well?

Comment: @AmitBaranes i dont have a stackblitz example for this as im using an Internal API so you wont be able reproduce this (you cant access this API on an outside network).

Comment: @nash11 i don't want to use a search filter for this. i want to use the check box filter i have but for some reason it works with one option but not with the other.

Answer (score 1):

There's some logical errors in your code. Where you are trying to add the filter to the `filterPredicate()`, you are instead rewriting the initially defined `filterPredicate()`. so your code must only be filtering through `LQOCH_SHM_LOEZI_QTSR` and not through `SOG_MCOLH`.

You can use `ngModel` or `formControlName` to bind to the value of the checkbox and call the `applyFilter()` function on change of the checkbox. I'm passing the filter as an object since it's easier to work with. Although, `mat-table` only accepts it as a string so you will need to use `JSON.stringify()`.

I have attached a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-checkbox-filter).

Comment: I have tried using your StackBlitz example and it didn't work for me. it just deleted the entire table when i pressed on the checkbox

Comment: That's weird. It's working fine for me. Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No it just turns from 1400 results to 0

Comment: added the stackblitz link

Comment: Just to be clear. when you said my stackblitz example didn't work for you, did you mean you tried to implement the same thing in yours and it didn't work or that the stackblitz example I put up isn't working? Also Please provide some dummy data for the table in your stackblitz example.

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution into my code and it didn't work for me. ill edit it now with some dummy data.

Comment: i have added dummy data